# Is it safe to put cooler pad beneath an external 2.5" HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, security, external-hard-drive, cooling

My external 2.5" HDD gets hot (>= 46 C) when being used for longer than 12h. I want to reach an ideal temperature between 25 and 40 celcius. So I put a cooler pad beneath the drive. But what I noticed is that the cooler makes vibration when it works.

As technical specs: the cooler fan speed is 1200 rpm, the noise level is 25dbA and power output is 1.75 W.

So can't cooler vibrations harm the disk? Is it safe to cool the drive that way?

Comment: You'll want to isolate the HDD from the case with rubber spacers in between the drive and the drive's mounting points in the case.  Depending on how strong the vibrations are, it can pose a risk to the HDD due to the heads having micrometer level spacing between the heads and the platters.

Comment: Hi @JW0914, the cooler is in fact designed for cooling laptops, and it is packaged in the form of pad (cooler pad). This link describes the cooler pad I'm using: https://www.nordic-digital.com/en/accessories/107-omega-laptop-cooler-pad-breeze-black-42151.

Comment: @JW0914 the speed of the fan is 1200 rpm, and noise level is 25dbA. Also the power output is 1.75 W.

Comment: I misread the question's title... if the external HDD is a 3.5", it has rubber bumpers that separate the HDD from the external mount points in the casing, and if it's a 2.5" external HDD, they often have rubber spacers as well... either way, there wouldn't be enough of a vibration coming from the cooler to affect the external drives.  If you're concerned, you can always buy small rubber spacers to place between the external HDD and the cooler pad on all four corners, which would still allow for ample air flow.

Comment: @JW0914 I see. Thanks a lot for your help.